# swallowing excessive saliva while fasting will break your roza or not?

Tags: salat, sawm, ramadan

Asslam o alaikum to all of my brothers and sisters.. Well my question is that i have searched in google that when a person swallow his saliva while fasting is this breaks persons fast..? Everywhere it shows that swallowing saliva will not breaks persons fast but whenever i do sehri after sehri my mouth suddenly filled with water till iftari so is this ok to swallow that much saliva?.. Most people do not fell that much saliva in their mouth as i do..Mostly i spit out but after 2 or 3 mint again my mouth fill with water.. Iam not good in english but i hope you get whatever i said. My question is only that is this ok to swallow that much saliva? But it's very hard for me to not to swallow saliva while praying salah in the month of ramadan.. We don't use tissues while praying salah so i swallow my saliva because there is no any other way of spitting out while praying salah specially in the month of ramdhan

Answer (score 0):

A renowned shaykh in Facebook wrote that it can break the fast, but I mostly think that it's a matter of opinions. In my opinion you should try to not swallow it, this is a safer option, otherwise ask a Alim and Allah knows best

Answer (score 0):

Swallowing unavoidable things such as one’s saliva,is not invalidate the fast. So excessive saliva will not breaks one's fast.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no connection with fast and saliva. Saliva is just your own body fluid, so swallowing it or not do not have effect on your fast. If you get too much obsessed with not trying to swallow saliva then the saliva will get produced more than it usually get produced. So better to leave it usual way and don't get obsessed with saliva, as it does not effect your fast in anyway.

Comment: What about urine drinking? does it break fast if it is your own urine? (srs)

Comment: urine is not produced in your mouth

Comment: Also as said above it is not produced in your mouth. If you are trying to say “is drinking urine allowed” then no it isn’t. Why would you drink your own urine anyway?

Answer (score 0):

### In the name of Allah, Most Gracious, Most Merciful

**All praise and thanks are due to Allah, the Lord of the worlds. We cannot find words to praise Him, as He only sees fit how laudation should be addressed to Him. We seek refuge in Allah from the evils within ourselves and the evils of our bad deeds. Whosoever Allah guides will never be led astray, and whosoever He leads astray will never find guidance. We bear witness that there is no god but Allah, the One without any associate, and We bear witness that Muhammad is His Messenger and bondman, peace and blessings be upon him, his kith and kin, his Companions and all those who follow their guidance until the Day of Judgment.**

---

**Your Question:** Swallowing excessive while fasting will break your roza or not?

**Answer:** If a fasting person swallows his saliva that does not invalidate his fast even if there is a lot of it and if that happens in the mosque or elsewhere.

Allah Says:

> "The month of Ramadan [is that] in which was revealed the Qur'an, a guidance for the people and clear proofs of guidance and criterion. So whoever sights [the new moon of] the month, let him fast it; and whoever is ill or on a journey - then an equal number of other days. Allah intends for you ease and does not intend for you hardship and [wants] for you to complete the period and to glorify Allah for that [to] which He has guided you; and perhaps you will be grateful." [[**The Cow, 2:185**](https://quran.com/2/185)]

What cannot be avoided, such as swallowing one’s saliva, does not invalidate the fast, because avoiding that is difficult. This is similar to dust on the road and the dust from flour. Even if a person lets saliva gather and swallows it deliberately, that does not invalidate his fast because it reaches his stomach in a similar way even if he does not let it gather.

> Narrated Abu Huraira:
>
> The Prophet said, "If somebody eats or drinks forgetfully then he should complete his fast, for what he has eaten or drunk, has been given to him by Allah." Narrated 'Amir bin Rabi'a, "I saw the Prophet cleaning his teeth with Siwak while he was fasting so many times as I can't count." And narrated Abu Huraira, "The Prophet said, 'But for my fear that it would be hard for my followers, I would have ordered them to clean their teeth with Siwak on every performance of ablution." The same is narrated by Jabir and Zaid bin Khalid from the Prophet who did not differentiate between a fasting and a nonfasting person in this respect (using Siwak).
>
> Aisha said, "The Prophet said, "It (i.e. Siwak) is a purification for the mouth and it is a way of seeking Allah's pleasures." Ata' and Qatada said, "There is no harm in swallowing the resultant saliva."
>
> ([**Sahih Al-Bukhari, Volume 3, Book 31, Number 154**](http://www.shariahprogram.ca/Hadith/Sahih-Bukhari/031.sbt.html))

---

**Sources:**

- [**Fasting person swallowing saliva and mucus**](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/12597/fasting-person-swallowing-saliva-and-mucus)
- [**Ruling on swallowing one’s own saliva or that of someone else**](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/49005/ruling-on-swallowing-ones-own-saliva-or-that-of-someone-else)